# Check if a data frame contains at least one zero value inside an if statement in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, if-statement

I have a dataframe in `R` as follows

```
df <-
  as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(0,1,2,3,4,5),c(1,2,4,5,6)))
```

and I have a function in which I want the procedure to stop and display a message if the input `df` contains at least one 0 value. I tried the following but can't make it work properly. What is the correct `if()` statement I should use?

```
my_function <- function(df){

  if (all(df == 0) == 'TRUE')
    stop(paste("invalid input df"))
}
```

Comment: `if(any(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE)) stop("invalid input df")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `%in%`

```
my_function <- function(df) {
     if(0 %in% unlist(df)) {
       stop("invalid input df")
     }
}
```